How to correctly execute output (with additional arguments) of find?
I'm executing output (with additional argument --version) of find in the following way:
$ find NDK -name clang -executable -type f | xargs -I{} bash -c "exec {} --version"
Android (7714059, based on r416183c1) clang version 12.0.8

It works. However, this way is perhaps sub-optimal.
Is there a correct / optimal way of doing this?

-exec is the right answer and you don't even need bash -c in this particular case. If you ever really need to use bash -c (or sh -c or so) with -exec (or with xargs), do not embed {} in the shell code. This means your "it works" is somewhat flawed in general.

Use -exec directly as find's option:
find NDK -name clang -executable -type f -exec {} --version \;


How to modify this command to show the result of find (e.g. file name) before executing {} --version? Expected output: <file name><newline><result of {} --version>.

For example ... -exec sh -c 'echo "$1"; "$1" --version' -- {} \;
